# Can I have the Google managed service range on a standard gke cluster created with Terraform- non auto-pilot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm confused about this, is this only auto-pilot? I thought I was going to get this on GKE standard too https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips#-managed_secondary_ranges_default

Can I enable this for new standard GKE clusters as well?

> For Autopilot clusters running GKE 1.27 and later, GKE assigns Service
> IP addresses from a Google-managed range by default 34.118.224.0/20,
> eliminating the need to specify your own range for Services. The
> following considerations apply...

The docs don't explicitly say auto-pilot only. Perhaps thats the case, but I'd like to confirm if there is a way to configure standard GKE for it as well.

## Edit

Adding more context, the following terraform creates a cluster with a service range in a `10.x.0.0/20` network. I can't see the option in the terraform resource to use the managed service range.

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "test01" {
  provider = google-beta
  name     = var.test01_name
  release_channel {
    channel = "STABLE"
  }
  private_cluster_config {
    enable_private_nodes   = true
    master_ipv4_cidr_block = var.test01_master_ipv4_cidr_block
  }

  remove_default_node_pool = true
  initial_node_count       = 1
  node_config {
    service_account = google_service_account.test.email
  }

  cluster_autoscaling {
    enabled = true
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "memory"
      minimum       = 0
      maximum       = 1000
    }
    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "cpu"
      minimum       = 0
      maximum       = 100
    }

    auto_provisioning_defaults {
      oauth_scopes = [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      ]
      service_account = google_service_account.test.email
      shielded_instance_config {
        enable_integrity_monitoring = true
        enable_secure_boot          = false
      }
    }
  }

  master_auth {
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = false
    }
  }

  location   = var.default_region
  network    = google_compute_network.net.id
  subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.net.id

  workload_identity_config {
    workload_pool = "${data.google_project.project.project_id}.svc.id.goog"
  }

  addons_config {
    http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false
    }
    gcp_filestore_csi_driver_config {
      enabled = true
    }
    gce_persistent_disk_csi_driver_config {
      enabled = true
    }
  }

  cost_management_config {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      node_pool,
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, when creating the autopilot cluster, you would only need to select the network and the primary range (node range) where your cluster will run. Additionally, you may create two secondary ranges for subnets, one for pods and the other for services. If you don't, as it says `for Autopilot clusters running GKE 1.27 and later, GKE assigns Service IP addresses from a Google-managed range by default (34.118.224.0/20), eliminating the need to specify your own range for Services. The following considerations apply.`
[image]

In GKE standard clusters, there is a checkbox that you can check to instruct GKE to automatically generate secondary IP ranges for both pods and services.
[image]

Let me know if it helps, or may be correct me if my understanding is incorrect about the question.

here [image]

email [image]

Comment: No, that just automatically selects a private CIDR, it does not use the managed service IP range. Did you actually create that cluster? Did you see it using `34.118.224.0/20` for its service range?

Comment: Indeed, it's using the 34.118.224.0/20 for its service range. Since comments doesn't allow you to post images, I've updated my ans with the image above

Comment: Do you know where this option is for the terraform resource? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster

Comment: Sorry I edited my question to be more specific. I'm trying to do this with terraform. Is it because its a private cluster? because I thought that wouldn't matter for this because the managed range isn't publicly accessible right?

Comment: Can you check this option? ```services_ipv4_cidr_block``` can be used to automatically create a GKE-managed one. 
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#:~:text=services_ipv4_cidr_block%20can%20be%20used%20to%20automatically%20create%20a%20GKE%2Dmanaged%20one.

Comment: @red888 quick update for your initial query ```The docs don't explicitly say auto-pilot only. Perhaps thats the case, but I'd like to confirm if there is a way to configure standard GKE for it as well.```  last year around Jun 2, 2023, you would have gotten an email from the GKE team stating the new managed range is for both Autopilot and std cluster. (I have added part of that email in my answer)

Comment: if you have anything to add about the terraform resource that would be appreciated as well. I might open a different issue for it.

Comment: @red888 A new question would be good, as it might get the attention of others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters#vpc-clusters), for clusters created in the Standard mode, the default network mode depends on the GKE version and the method you use to create the cluster.

Comment: VPC native doesn't matter regarding this feature. I created a new VPC native standard cluster and it did not use the managed IP range.